# How to get return type of a Python function's signature if it's not annotated?

Tags: python, return-type

I am trying to collect documentation about Python functions: mandatory arguments, option arguments, return type...

I am having trouble figuring out how to get return type. Most functions don't have this annotated, so I get:

```
inspect.Signature.empty
```

when using:

```
inspect.Signature.return_annotation
```

I am interested in something like **Series or DataFrame** from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas.Series.clip). Is there a way to do it without going through help documentation?

Comment: That's a bit difficult in a dynamic language like Python. E.g. `def foo(bar): return bar`. At best you could annotate that as taking `T` and returning `T`. Not to mention all the runtime shenanigans you could do that would elude any static analyser.

Comment: @deceze I was thinking of functions you get with pandas, pyplot, etc... Is the help documentation the only place anything about return values is written?